# Last access date of PDF file not automatically set to today's date when opened in a PDF reader?

Tags: ntfs, file-management

In Windows 7 Explorer, when I open a PDF document in any PDF Reader (e.g. Foxit Reader), the `Last Accessed` attribute of the PDF file date is not automatically set to today's date as the "last accessed" term would suggest. Why not? Isn't the PDF file being ACCESSED by the opening program?

It seems that even after having opened this same PDF file in the last days for several times, the PDF file still keeps its older Last accessed date.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the last-access time whenever a file is opened adds a lot of writes to disk for operations that appear to only be reads. That degrades performance, and literally degrades certain types of storage media that can only sustain a finite number of writes. Therefore, starting in Windows Vista, [the last-access time is no longer kept up to date](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2006/11/07/disabling-last-access-time-in-windows-vista-to-improve-ntfs-performance/) by default. So though you are indeed accessing the file, your computer doesn't write that piece of information.

If you want it to keep track of files' last access, run this command, then reboot:

```
fsutil behavior set DisableLastAccess 0
```